# li and ul with submenus conditionally displayed

Tags: php, javascript, html, html-lists

I created a page with an header. This header.php has the following format:

```
<?php
$index_admin = "/test/index_test.php";
...
?>

<div id="button"> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href=<?=$index_test?>><span class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($index_test)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">test</span></a></li>
    ...
  </ul> 
</div>
```

where

```
$currentpath = basename(__FILE__)
```

setted in every page before

```
include "header.php"
```

So when I open the page index_test I have the class buttonon, which changes the color of my link (so it's displaied as active).

Now I'd like to create an hidden submenu of the li which looks like:

```
<li><a href=<?=$index_test?>><span class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($index_test))    {echo("buttonon");} ?>">test</span></a></li>
     <ul style="display:none">
         <li>...</li>
```

which is displaied only if I go only over the

```
<li>
```

with

```
<onmouseover:"callfunctiontoshowthesubmenu">.
```

There I am.

My problem is: when I open a page listed on the submenu, I want to keep the submenu displayed. How can I do that?

Which is the fastest way?

Comment: Does your menu have classes on it to indicate the active page, or are you starting from scratch with page detection?

Comment: The buttonon echoed in the php part in the li is a class

Comment: Can you then use JS (jQuery, ideally), to show the UL under the LI with the active class?